# Cоздание кастомного Entry MAUI

Tags: .net, xamarin, maui

подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно кастомизировать поле Entry в .NET MAUI? Под кастомизацией понимаю например добавление рамки вокруг, какую-то иконку перед полем набора текста.
Пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Был бы очень рад также ссылке на документацию, где прописано, каким образом такое делается. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы такое сделать, я обычно создаю новое *представление* **ContentView** в отдельном файле. Подробнее про это можно почитать в [документации MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/contentview?view=net-maui-7.0).

Затем добавляю необходимые *свойства*, которые будут доступны при использовании элемента (например свойство **Text** или **IsValid**, и т.д.). Это также описано в документации. Обратите внимание, что для привязки используется специальный *тип* - **BindableProperty**.

Код разметки вашего *нового компонента* будет выглядеть примерно следующим образом:

```
<ContentView ...>
    <HorizontalStackLayout>
        <Image/>
        <Entry/>
    </HorizontalStackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

А для использования его в коде нужно указать *пространство имён*, в котором находится новый компонент и его использовать как и другие компоненты:

```
<ContentPage 
    ...
    xmlns:entry="clr-namespace:YourApp.Path.To.Component">
    <HorizontalStackLayout>
        <entry:EntryComponent/>
    </HorizontalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Разметка и привязка других пространств ***могут отличаться***, советую свериться с документацией.